# Shopify - Add Element with Multiple Variant If Quantity is Zero

Tags: jquery, shopify

I was able to add **"disabled"** when the product variant quantity is zero however this only work when the product has a single option. When I add multiple option it will stop working  and when I used **"unless"** the other product get affected.

For example, the product size are Small and Large and the color is Black and Blue, the quantity of Small Black = 10 and the quantity of Medium Black is 0.

if I used variant quantity here, the class is added to both Small Black and Medium black even if the  Medium black is the only one that has 0 variant

```
single-option-selector__radio{% unless variant_label_state %} disabled{% endunless %}"
```

Code for handling the **"disabled"**

```
<fieldset class="single-option-radio {{ option.name }}"
                      name="{{ option.name }}"
                      id="ProductSelect-option-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                      {% assign option_index = forloop.index %}
                      {% for value in option.values %}
                        {% assign variant_label_state = true %}
                        {% if product.options.size == 1 %}
                          {% unless product.variants[forloop.index0].available  %}
                            {% assign variant_label_state = false %}
                          {% endunless %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <input type="radio"
                          {% if option.selected_value == value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
                          value="{{ value | escape }}"
                          data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
                          name="{{ option.name }}"
                          class="single-option-selector__radio{% unless variant_label_state %} disabled{% endunless %}"
                          id="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name }}-{{ value | escape | remove: " " }}" >
                        <label  for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name }}-{{ value | escape | remove: " " }}"{% unless variant_label_state %} class="disabled"
                               {% endunless %}
                               data-variant="{{ value | escape }}">{{ value | escape }}</label>
                      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this theme you have to create this sold out disable product functionality using your custom code like Liquid Code, Html etc.

Thanks !!